# LazyColumn inside Column with verticalScroll modifier throws exception

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, jetpack-compose-column

In one of my composables, a `Lazycolumn` is nested inside a `Column` composable. I want to be able to scroll the entire `Column` along with the `Lazycolumn`. But, specifying the `verticalScroll` `modifier` property on `Column` results in the following exception causing the app to crash. How can I fix this?

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()).
```

**Composable**

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .padding(bottom = 100.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        items(
            items = allItems!!,
            key = { item ->
                item.id
            }
        ) { item ->
            ShoppingListScreenItem(
                navController = navController,
                item = item,
                sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
            ) { isChecked ->
                scope.launch {
                    shoppingListScreenViewModel.changeItemChecked(item!!, isChecked)
                }
            }
        }
    }

   ...

Button(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 24.dp),
    onClick = {
        navController.navigate(NavScreens.AddItemScreen.route) {
            popUpTo(NavScreens.AddItemScreen.route) {
                inclusive = true
            }
        }
    }
) {
    Text("Go to add item screen")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you wish to measure your `LazyColumn` with `Constraints` with `Constraints.Infinity` for the maxHeight which is not permitted as described in error log. There should be a fixed height or you shouldn't have another Scrollable with same orientation.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
         // This is the cause
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    LazyColumn(
       // and not having a Modifier that could return non-infinite max height contraint
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {

}
```

If you don't know exact height you can assign `Modifier.weight(1f)` to LazyColumn.

#### Contraints

This section is extra about `Constraints` and measurement you can skip this part if you are not interested in how it works.

What i mean by measuring with with Constraints.Infinity is when you create a `Layout` in Compose you use

```
Layout(modifier=modifier, content=content){
     measurables: List<Measurable>, constraints: Constraints ->
}
```

You get child Composables as `List<Measurable>` which you can measure with `Constraints` provided by parent or the one you see fit by updating existing one with `Constraints.copy` or fixed one when you build a custom Composable with `Layout`.

```
val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
```

Constraints `min/max` `width/height` changes based on size modifier or scroll. When there is a scroll and you don't use any size modifier, `Constraints` return
minHeight =0, maxHeight= Int.MAX_VALUE as `Constraints.Infinity`

```
Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
```

[image]

```
Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(1f)
```

[image]

Easiest way to check `Constraints` with different Modifiers or with scroll is getting it from `BoxWithConstraints`

Comment: I just set the height on the `LazyColumn` and there's no exception thrown, but setting a height greater than the total number of items in the `LazyColumn` causes the screen to pull back when flick scrolling. How can I fix that?

Comment: Placing `Modifier.weight(1f)` on the `LazyColumn` causes the Lazy list to completely disappear on the screen.

Comment: I made an example with simple items using `Modifier.weight(1f)`, image above is from that it worked fine setting same height to LazyColumn. Comment your LazyColumn and put a BoxWithConstraints to check the max height you get. But you might not need Column in the first place. You might achieve what you wish with only `LazyColumn` with a structure for instance `item{Header()}`  `items({your items}` and `item{Footer()}`. And it's strange issue with pull back i don't know why it occurs especially without testing layout.

Comment: You might check this video about it https://youtu.be/1ANt65eoNhQ?t=898